# WooCommerce and Porto Theme - Fatal Error: Cannot redeclare print_porto_social_login()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I recently upgraded the woocommerce plugin and now I am facing following issue.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare print_porto_social_login() 
(previously declared ../var/www...:40) 
in /var/www (same path as previous one) on line 62
```

The file is from Porto theme and I think it's sth like compatibility issue between woocommerce and porto.
I checked the file and also did a global search on project wide but there's only one function with the given name.
I am really not sure what's going on here.

Comment: You already have the function `print_porto_social_login` defined. It even tells you the file path and line numbers.

Comment: I already mentioned it's telling the same file and in that file there's only one function. anyway thanks for commenting @AndrewHardiman.

Comment: How were you able to solve it?